# PyQGIS Finding duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, duplication

I have a table with three columns that I'm interested in: X, Y and rotate. These specify the position and angle of a symbol. I want to find duplicates across these columns, so anything with the same X,Y co-ords which also has the same angle set. I can find duplicates in geometry but not by finding the angle as well. I thought along the line of a For loop with nested If statements, but am unsure how to set that up - I'm a bit of a beginner with PyQGIS. This the code I'm using to find the duplicates which was found elsewhere on this forum:

```
layer = subscriber_feed_layer
allfeatures={}
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for ft in layer.getFeatures():
    allfeatures[ft.id()] = ft
    index.insertFeature(ft)

selection = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    inGeom = feat.geometry()
    idsList = index.intersects(inGeom.boundingBox())
    if len(idsList) > 1:
        for id in idsList:
            selection.append(allfeatures[id])
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

Comment: find all the geometry duplicates, then look for symbol angle duplicates in that list?

Comment: Please, add a snippet of your code in order to receiving potential answers. As it's currently written, it's hard to give you any help.

Comment: This is the code I'm using to find the geometry duplicates:

Comment: @K.Osborne are you dealing with point features? Is "rotate" a field of your layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the geometry duplicates, I've used a dictionary to find the same angle among them. Assuming that *'rotate'* is the name of the field in your layer containing the angle of symbol, I've made a few changes to the code. Following should work for you -

```
layer = subscriber_feed_layer
allfeatures={}
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for ft in layer.getFeatures():
    allfeatures[ft.id()] = ft
    index.insertFeature(ft)

selection = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    inGeom = feat.geometry()
    idsList = index.intersects(inGeom.boundingBox())
    if len(idsList) > 1:
        d = {}
        for id in idsList:
            rot_ang = allfeatures[id]['rotate']
            if rot_ang in d:
                selection.append(allfeatures[id])
                selection.append(allfeatures[ d[rot_ang] ])
            else:
                d[rot_ang] = id
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```